# Javascript - convert array of arrays into array of objects with prefilled values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have following array:

```
[
    [val1, val2]
    [val1, val2]
    [val1, val2]
    [valN, valN]
]
```

`N` represents the fact that these arrays are not limited, i.e I never know how much of them do I store. What I try to accomplish is converting that array to array of objects with keys `lat` and `lng` and I expect so have final result as following so I can use it for further needs:

```
[
    {
        lat: val1,
        lng: val2
    },
    {
        lat: val1,
        lng: val2
    },
    {
        lat: valN,
        lng: valN
    }
]
```

I found a function to convert these inner arrays to objects and it looks like this:

```
objectify(array) {
    return array.reduce(function(result, currentArray) {
        result[currentArray[0]] = currentArray[1];
        return result;
    }, {});
}
```

It works but output looks like this:

```
[
    {val1: val1, val2: val2}
    {val1: val1, val2: val2}
    {valN: valN, valN: valN}
]
```

and that's not what I'm looking for, because I really need these `lat` and `lng` to be keys of an object. How can I solve such issue?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can simply use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to project an array into another one by applying a projection function:

```js
var arrs = [
    [1, 2],
    [3, 4],
    [5, 6],
    [7, 8]
];

var objs = arrs.map(x => ({ 
  lat: x[0], 
  lng: x[1] 
}));

/* or, using the older "function" syntax:

var objs = arrs.map(function(x) { 
  return {
    lat: x[0], 
    lng: x[1] 
  };
);

*/

console.log(objs);
```

Comment: Thank you Yeldar, it worked perfecly fine for me! I will accept it as answer in about 5 minutes in case your post was the first one to come.

Answer (score 16):

Using ES6 you can write this in a very concise way:

```js
var arrs = [
    [1, 2],
    [3, 4],
    [5, 6],
    [7, 8]
];
const locations = arrs.map(([lat, lng]) => ({lat, lng}));
console.log(locations);
```

Comment: how can I make it like this?
[ { 1 : 2 } , { 3 : 4 } , { 5 : 6 } , { 7 : 8 } ]

Comment: @fazeelzama Replace `{lat, lng}` with `{[lat]: lng}`.

Comment: i need to do same thing but i have arrs.map is not a function

Comment: @Versifiction You should ask a new question and provide details with actual code. There is absolutely no way to know what you're doing with just that comment alone.

Comment: here's my topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60999060/convert-oracle-query-output-to-json-oracle-nodejs

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to achieve this. Array#map passes each array element through a projection function and returns the values in a new array.

```js
var data= [
    ['val1', 'val2'],
    ['val1', 'val2'],
    ['val1', 'val2'],
    ['valN', 'valN'],
];

var result = data.map(function(row) {
  return {
    lat: row[0],
    lng: row[1]
  };
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: i need to do same thing but i have data.map is not a function

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array = [
    ['val1', 'val2'],
    ['val1', 'val2'],
    ['val1', 'val2'],
    ['valN', 'valN']
];

var arrayObject = array.map(function(item){ 
  return { lat: item[0], lng: item[1]};
});

console.log(arrayObject);
```

Comment: i need to do same thing but i have array.map is not a function