# Passing JSON from React to Spring Controller

Tags: java, json, spring, reactjs

So I'm trying to send some data using fetch.

```
console.log(results.data);
```

`results.data` is what I am trying to send. The code above gives me the following in the console:

> [Array[52], Array[52], Array[52], Array[52], Array[52], Array[52],
>   Array[52], Array[52], Array[52], Array[52], Array[52], Array[52],
>   Array[52], Array[52], Array[52], Array[1]]

This leads me to believe that I should be expecting a `String[][]` in the controller

This is the react code:

```
fetch('/device', {
  method: 'post',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({data : results.data})
}).then(res=>res.json())
  .then(res => console.log(res));
```

and controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/deviceIngestion", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody String deviceIngestion (@RequestParam(value = "data[][]") String[][] data) {

    return data [0][0];
}
```

but i get this response in the console:

> Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String[][] parameter 'data[][]' is not present

I've also come across this error after trying some other things:

> "Could not read document: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String[][] out of START_OBJECT token↵ at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@2f36dd94; line: 1, column: 1]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String[][] out of START_OBJECT token↵ at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@2f36dd94; line: 1, column: 1]"
>   path
>   :
>   "/deviceIngestion"
>   status
>   :
>   400
>   timestamp
>   :
>   1513693466676
>   Name

I've also tried to create a class with `ArrayList<String[]>` in the constructor to replace the `String[][]` that I'm using in the controller but no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seemed to be Java not being able to understand the format that the JSON was in, that being:
 `[[x,y],[a,b]]`
In order to solve it I changed the JSON into an array of objects 
`[{x:x, y:y},{x:a,y:b}]`[see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45186096/javascript-convert-array-of-arrays-into-array-of-objects-with-prefilled-values)

After that I created a Java class that matched the objects which were being stored in the JSON array and changed the controller to the following:

```
@PostMapping("/device")
public String deviceIngestion (@RequestBody List<DeviceData> devices) throws IOException{
    return "success";        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the data in the request body so in your controller you should try `public @ResponseBody String deviceIngestion (@RequestBody String[][] data)...` although I've not convinced myself this will work either, worth a try or playing around with though.

**UPDATE** Your pojo should look like:

```
public class DataObject {
    String[][] data;
    public String[][] getData() {
        return data;
    }
    public void setData(String[][] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }    
}
```

and the controller should look like:

```
public @ResponseBody String deviceIngestion (@RequestBody DataObject data)...
```

Comment: This is what I originally tried, it gives the second error that I mentioned, though I think it is one step closer to the solution, thanks

Comment: Can you post the actual JSON of results.data rather than the console log, that may or may not help!

Comment: It contains company sensitive data so no, but its just one array filled with 16 String arrays with 52 Strings inside each one

Comment: So, correct me if I'm wrong, you are sending an object with a field called data which contains an array of 16 other arrays which each contain 52 String objects? If that's the case then String[][] data is incorrect.

Comment: Yes I believe thats right, what should String[][] be replaced with?

Comment: I was trying to work it out. I think you need to create a pojo java class which contains the String[][] field. I was trying to use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to help, but as you know the data it might be worth seeing what it comes up with for you.

Comment: I have added a quick demo to git which works. I created a Spring back end at https://github.com/cr41g/demo and a react client at https://github.com/cr41g/demo-client. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you but I found a solution, I posted an answer so you can see what the issue was.

Answer (score 0):

`body: JSON.stringify({data : results.data})`

`@RequestParam(value = "data[][]")`

1) You are passing **data** but controller expects **data[][]**

2) If you pass String[][] then you should send it like 
`body: JSON.stringify(results.data)` not `body: JSON.stringify({data : results.data})`. However if you **have to** use your original form then you may try to create a wrapper class like

```
public class Body {
   private String[][] data;
}
```

And use it in controller like

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/deviceIngestion", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody String deviceIngestion (@RequestBody Body body) {
    String[][] data = body.getData();
    return data[0][0];
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to not perform JSON.stringify(...) and just pass an object as-is?

Comment: Another option I would try is to explicitly declare `consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE` (instead of produces) in @RequestMapping