# How to access an array within an array without keys in React?

Tags: arrays, reactjs

This is the data being sent from the server:

[[10031,2],[10054,1],[10141,3],[10247,4],[10266,1],[10278,1],[10336,1],[10509,5],[10743,2],[12159,3],[12185,2],[12186,2],[12189,1],[12233,1],[12271,2],[12335,1],[12520,3],[12521,5],[12541,1]]

The 5-digit number is an ID, and the single digit number is a quantity. If there were keys, it would be easier to access, but I only have values. I want to access the ID and the quantity separately. I also want to put all IDs into one array, and all quantities into a parallel array.

Here is what I have tried so far that sort of accesses the values separately:

```
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.chartData.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < this.state.chartData[i].length; j++) {
        console.log(this.state.chartData[i][j]);
      }
    }
```

The above code returns this in the console:

```
10031
2
10054
1
10141
3
10247
4
10266
1
10278
1
10336
1
10509
5
10743
2
12159
3
12185
2
12186
2
12189
1
12233
1
12271
2
12335
1
12520
3
12521
5
12541
1
```

Trying to set the state to this however results in an error. I'm currently trying to teach myself react, so I'm not as familiar with my options and have been struggling to find a solution.

I feel like I might be missing something obvious here. I also likely have the option to do this in the backend in spring boot/java and then return that.

Comment: How do you try to set your state

Comment: @BurakGavas 

```
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.chartRawData.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < this.state.chartRawData[i].length; j++) {
        this.setState({ chartKey: this.state.chartRawData[i][j] });
      }
    }
```

This results in a maximum update depth exceeded

Comment: It is not good to call 'setState' many times. Instead set your state as data once. If data is not appropriate to use in your chart, then restructure the data accordingly and set state.

Comment: That's not "an array within an array object without keys". That's just an array of arrays (aka a multidimensional array). If you just want to convert that to an array of objects, see [Javascript - convert array of arrays into array of objects with prefilled values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45186096/215552)

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you need to do with the data and why you even need to set state with it. Seems the existing shape is sufficient for rendering by simply mapping over the array and using array destructuring to get the vars like `data.map(([id, quantity]) => <Bar label={id} quantity={quantity} />`

Answer (score 1):

```
const obj = Object.fromEntries(yourData);
console.log(obj) // {10031: 2, 10054: 1, 10141: 3, .... }
```

> I also want to put all IDs into one array, and all quantities into a parallel array.

```
const keys = Object.keys(obj); // Array of keys [10031, 100254...]
const values = Object.values(obj); // Array of values [2,1, ...]
```

Comment: Yup this works! Was not aware of the Object.fromEntries method