# JSON.parse is failing for resultset from Oracle DB in Node.js

Tags: node.js, oracle, graphql, resultset, apollo-server

Following the solution provided in [Demo: GraphQL with Oracle Database and node-oracledb](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/post/demo-graphql-with-oracle-database-and-node-oracledb), I created a simple Node JS application with Apollo GraphQL. However, I am stuck at converting the result set obtained from Oracle DB to desired form as expected by the GraphQL schema. If
I use JSON.Parse on resultset as shown in the link I mentioned above, it is throwing error -

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token O in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse
> () at Object.getAssets.. executeQuery.js:39:19

This is my first ever code in Node.js and I am still learning. Hence, Can someone please help me understand why is it not working for me. I am logging the results obtained from DB and it's returning 10 records as expected.

Here is my code:

GraphQL schema definition: schema.js

```
const { gql } = require("apollo-server");

const typeDefs = gql`
    type Asset {
        id: ID!
        account_id: String
        group_id: String            
    }
    
    type Query {
        assets: [Asset]
    }
    `;

module.exports = typeDefs;
```

Resolver : resolvers.js

```
const queryrunner = require("./executeQuery.js")

const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        assets: async() => queryrunner.getAssets(),
    },
};

module.exports = resolvers;
```

Fetching connection from file oracledatasource.js

```
let connection;
var oracledb = require('oracledb');

module.exports = {
  getConnection : function () {
      
    connection = oracledb.getConnection({
    user          : "username",
    password      : "password",
    connectString : "(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = hostname)(PORT = 1521))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVICE_NAME = servicename)))"
  });
  console.log("Successfully connected to Oracle!")
  return connection;
  }
}
```

And executing query in executeQuery.js :

```
    const conn = require('./oracledatasource')

    module.exports = {

    getAssets : async() => {
      let connection = await conn.getConnection();
      let query = "SELECT\r\n"
            + "    CA.ASSET_ID as id,\r\n"
            + "    CA.ACCNT_ID as account_id,\r\n"
            + "    CA.GROUP_ID as group_id\r\n"         
            + "FROM\r\n"
            + "    SCHEMA.TABLE CA\r\n"
            + "WHERE\r\n"
            + "        CA.ACTIVE_FLG = 1\r\n"
            + "    AND ROWNUM <= 10";

      console.log(query);
      let result = await connection.execute(query, []);
      connection.release(); 
      
      console.log(result.rows);
      
      return JSON.parse(result.rows);
    }      
  }
```

index.js is my main file:

```
const { ApolloServer } = require("apollo-server");
    
const typeDefs = require('./schema');
    
const resolvers = require('./resolvers');
    
const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers
    //mocks: true
});
    
server.listen().then(({url}) =>
    console.log(`Server running at ${url}`)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution given for this question - [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60999060/convert-oracle-query-output-to-json-oracle-nodejs) helped to get the desired response.

I followed this manual as suggested - [node-oracledb](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#queryoutputformats) and passed outformat to execute() function, which returned the response as an array of objects. This eliminated the need of using JSON.parse.

```
  const conn = require('./oracledatasource')
  var oracledb = require('oracledb');

  module.exports = {

    getAssets : async() => {
      let connection = await conn.getConnection();
      let query = "SELECT\r\n"
            + "    CA.ASSET_ID \"id\",\r\n"
            + "    CA.ACCNT_ID \"account_id\",\r\n"
            + "    CA.GROUP_ID \"group_id\"\r\n"
            + "FROM\r\n"
            + "    SCHEMA.TABLE CA\r\n"
            + "WHERE\r\n"
            + "        CA.ACTIVE_FLG = 1\r\n"
            + "    AND ROWNUM <= 10";

      console.log(query);
      let result = await connection.execute(query, [], { outFormat: oracledb.OUT_FORMAT_OBJECT });
      connection.release(); 
      
      console.log(result.rows);
      
      return Object.values(result.rows);      
    }      
  }
```