# Assign Keys when converting array to json - Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json

I Have some array like below:

```
[
  [
    'James',
     23,
     'male'
  ],
  [
     'Britney',
     45,
     'female'
  ]
]
```

I would like to turn that into a json looking like:

```
[
{
    'name': 'James',
     'age': 23,
     'gender'': 'male'
},
{
    'name': 'Britney',
     'age': 45,
     'gender'': 'female'
}
]
```

I understand the json stringify part to convert the array to json but not sure how to create the keys for the values in an efficient way.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use the method suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45186342/5648954): `arr.map(([name, age, gender]) => ({name, age, gender}));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use map, then destruct the array and return an object.

```js
const arr = [
  [
    'James',
    23,
    'male'
  ],
  [
    'Britney',
    45,
    'female'
  ]
]

const res = arr.map(([name, age, gender]) => ({
    name,
    age,
    gender
}))

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Perfect thanks that did it!!  Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `map` with proper destructuring(for shortcut):

```js
var a=[ [ 'James', 23, 'male' ], [ 'Britney',45,'female']];

var result = a.map(([name,age,gender])=>({name, age, gender}));

console.log(result);
```