# How to convert array of array to array of objects in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am having an array of arrays shown below

```
const arrayOfArrays = [
  ['Lettuce', 60],
  ['Apple', 80]
];
```

how do I convert it to an array object with a key of name and price like:

```
const arrayOfObjects = [
 {name: 'Lettuce', price: 60},
 {name: 'Apple', price: 80},
];
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript - convert array of arrays into array of objects with prefilled values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45186096/javascript-convert-array-of-arrays-into-array-of-objects-with-prefilled-values)

Comment: Also remember that react is just javascript. Any questions about basic data type behaviour is not a "how do I do this in react" but really "how do I do this in JS" question =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using For Loop**

```
const x = [
 ['Lettuce', 60],
 ['Apple', 80]
]

let arrayOfObjects = []
for(let [name, price] of x){
    arrayOfObjects.push({name, price})
}
```

**Using map**

```
const x = [
 ['Lettuce', 60],
 ['Apple', 80]
]

let arrayOfObjects = x.map(([name, price]) => ({name,price}))
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to iterate over the items, and take the first value for the name, and the second value for the price:

```
const convertedArray = initialArray.map(item => {name:item[0],price:item[1])
```

Comment: I downvoted you when your answer was wrong. Now that you edited, I remove my vote. But I can now point at your behavior of accusing me of doing something that I am not doing. Please respect the others. If you are getting downvoted, it is for a reason. You udated 3 times, with 3 different approach, so get responses accordingly to what you post, it is how StackOverflow works, isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

I want to emphasize this has nothing to do with React, but it's plain javascript:

Basically you need to re-map your current array into a new format, can be done with the shortest code possible:

```js
.map(([k,v]) => ({name:k, price:v}))
```

and the `[k,v]` part is a simple [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#syntax)

```js
console.log(

  // original data
  [
    ['Lettuce', 60],
    ['Apple', 80]
  ]
  // conversion:
  .map(([k,v]) => ({name:k, price:v}))

)
```

Comment: This is an obvious duplicate. Asked and answered many times.

Comment: yes I know. I also feel bad for bothering to answer. OP seriously didn't take 2 minutes to google it...

Comment: Neither did you... :p

Comment: @HereticMonkey - I gave my answer for my own amusement, nothing more